# Как спарсить прямую ссылку на торрент Lostfilm ?

Tags: torrent

После обновления Lostfilm не получается спарсить ссылку на торрент файл.На сайте после нажатия на кнопку скачать меня переводить на эту страницу
http://retre.org/v3/?c=260&s=2&e=8&u=515898&h=aefe95670992248cb603259b51b535e0&n=1 
Как мне сформировать параметр `h=aefe95670992248cb603259b51b535e0`?
Если я хочу скачать торрент то ссылка имеет вид http://tracktor.in/td.php?s=Cczp3pShyiA1coXurKHZauULAnb9bb9hJQ1sMamdMAO9Uv93yTC1HVH7YbxlI3vIELSExN8OjDpYL3xHaYd5R2HCz6b1%2F3rkttNOHTwd1tibzgofoSEWRaEl4GghI9r0

Как формируется параметр `s=Cczp3pShyiA1coXurKHZauULAnb9bb9hJQ1sMamdMAO9Uv93yTC1HVH7YbxlI3vIELSExN8OjDpYL3xHaYd5R2HCz6b1%2F3rkttNOHTwd1tibzgofoSEWRaEl4GghI9r0`?

Comment: чем вы собираетесь обрабатывать ссылки?

Comment: Javascript или Ruby